# Копирование текста из защищённого PDF файла в браузере

Tags: pdf

Пытаюсь скопировать текст из защищённого pdf файла в браузере Microsoft edge, других браузеров нет, как и интернета на пк.

Просмотрел исходный код страницы, но ничего не нашёл. Как можно скопировать текст из файла?

Comment: Принтскринь, потом вставь в программу по распознаванию текста. А вообще трудно советовать, не видя файла. Дайте ссылку, тогда нам будет проще помочь.

Comment: Я не могу дать ссылку или сам файл, тк нет интернета на пк. Если бы был бы хотя бы интернет, то смог бы через python или готовые программы все сделать

Comment: Ну тогда никак, переписывайте руками